# Shrink text to table cell

Tags: javascript, css

Maybe it's an easy question, but there seems to be no obvious answer.

I have a table with a fixed layout (cells can't resize without screwing up the entire layout) and some dynamic text inside some cells. In case the text overflows, the text should shrink to fit inside the cell, instead of being clipped or wrapped.

I actually expected had to be a good CSS solution, but I failed to find any. Do I really have to do this manually using JavaScript?

Any idea? (best solution would be to not put dynamic text inside a fixed layout table, of course, but in this case there's no way around).

Comment: I'm thinking that, other than the possibility of an awesome algorithm, one would need to check for overflow, shrink, check, shrink, and so on until the text fits.

Comment: Problem finally solved by not exporting to HTML at all and going the PostScript -> GhostScript -> PNG path instead. Publishing Excel spreadsheets was finally more complicated than expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to be the guy that says "you can't", but today I'll have to be that guy.  Unfortunately there is no way to dynamically size text based on the length of a text string using only CSS.  You'll certainly have to solve this using JavaScript.

Comment: One other option, of course, is that if you're building your page server side with PHP or Java for example, you could add inline styling to cells that need to be resized like this: `<td style='font-size:80%'>`

Comment: Of course, I can pre-process the text and add this based on the length of the content. Hackish solution though, so I am looking for something better.

Answer (score 2):

Different font sizes on a table is going to look horrific, if acceptable, clip the text with `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` and add a tooltip so people can see the clipped text

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still interested in this, I wrote a PHP function to wrap the text in a span class and control the size. You can play with the `$maxLength` and `$divisor` variables to get it right for your table and then apply the function globally:

```
    function ShrinkText($text)
    {
        $maxLength = 20; // The length at which to start shrinking.
        $divisor = 5; // The factor to shrink by

        /*
         * A divisor of 5 with a string of 30 would do the following:
         *
         * $diff = (30 - 20)                                     [10]
         * $multiplier = ($diff / $divisor) * 10     [(10/5)*10 = 20]
         * $percentage = 100 - $multiplier            [100 - 20 = 80]
         * 
         * Output = '<span style="font-size:80%;">' . $text . '</span>'
         *
         */

        if(strlen($text) > $maxLength)
        {
            $diff = (strlen($text) - $maxLength);
            $multiplier = ($diff / $divisor) * 10;
            $percentage = 100 - $multiplier;

            return '<span style="font-size:' . $percentage . '%;">' . $text . '</span>';
        }
        else
        {
            return $text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (Original answer was 8 years ago), using "vw" instead "px" on text-size does the magic. Left this for future references to whom may need this info.

For a detailed reference of setting CSS font-size on webpages, please read [this reference site](https://medium.com/level-up-web/the-difference-between-css-units-px-pt-rem-em-vh-vw-ch-ex-and-the-rest-b2cfdf069230) - [Backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20221226010116/https://medium.com/level-up-web/the-difference-between-css-units-px-pt-rem-em-vh-vw-ch-ex-and-the-rest-b2cfdf069230).

Comment: Links to third party sites may disappear, to support others in future please share the code that is relevant to answering the question along with your explanation of how it should work.